# Is it necessary to finish quran with molvi sitting front of you when u are finishing it first time

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

Is it necessary to finish the quran with a molvi sitting in front of you because im 18 and still havent finished the quran because whenever i start till middle my molvi sometimes goes to village and never come back and this happe s several times with me so i want to ask that if i could recite and complete my quran alone or not? I can recite well though

Comment: What is a molvi, and what exactly do you mean by completing the quran?

Comment: A molvi is a person who often teaches Quran to children and lead prayers in the mosque. Just like Imams.@Medi1Saif

Answer (score 1):

You need a teacher to teach you the proper pronunciation and to correct your mistakes. This is a practical necessity rather than a doctrinal requirement.

If your teacher leaves in the middle, get a new one and resume from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

None of the hadith speak about speciality or uniqueness of completely reading the quran for first time. Quran is for understanding and putting it to practice and not for reading it like a parrot.

Since completing Quran in presence of moulvi is not any conditions laid down in shariah, you can complete it. And observing ceremonies, distribution of sweetmeat are all innovations if an individual completes Quran for first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is essential that you recite to who knows the Qur'an to ensure you reciting it correctly
if you do not have access to a teacher or you do not want to, you can follow the online Quran learning tools which could be harder for many
www.learnquran.ca